# Laravel - Save numerous entries to database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

First question, please indicate if it can be clarified.
I've used StackOverflow answers many times, so thanks for the help !

The website I'm developing needs to import many entries from a CSV file.
The transformation of the data and save is working at the moment, but since there can be several thousand entries in one file, importing the data to the DB can be VERY long.

What is the best way to save a big array of entries (array of arrays containing the data for each entry) to DB ?

Here is the code I'm using at the moment :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($participants); $i ++)
    {
        Participant::firstOrCreate( [ 'survey_id' => $participants[$i]['survey_id'],
            'id_importe' => $participants[$i]['id_importe'] ],
            array_merge( $participants[$i], ['token' => $savedInLime[$i]['token']] ) );
    }
```

I kept the construction of the array in there, but the important part is : is there a better way than looping in the array and "firstOrCreating" every entry ?

---

EDIT

I tested these methods with a timer on each for a file containing approximately 3900 entries.

TLDR : "create" is only slightly faster that "firstOrCreate" and "insert" is far slower because of the double loop.

1 - I used my previous code for firstOrCreate and it took 216s

2 - I used this code for "create" and it was slightly faster (205s) but does not ensure the entry isn't a copy

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($participants); $i ++)
    {
        Participant::create( 
            'id_importe' => $participants[$i]['id_importe'] ],
            array_merge( $participants[$i], ['token' => $savedInLime[$i]['token']] ) );
    }
```

3 - I used this code for the insert (maybe it could have been done faster with an array function) and it took 460s.
I had to use array_chunk because of the database placeholder limit (a little above 60k I believe).

```
    $tmp = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($participants); $i ++){
        $tmp[] = array_merge( $participants[$i], ['token' => $savedInLime[$i]['token']] );
    }
    $inserts = array_chunk($tmp, 2000);
    foreach ($inserts as $insert){
        Participant::insert($insert);
    }
```

Comment: And you're not sure if a particular entry is already in the DB or not, so you have to check it before entering it. Is that so?

Comment: Try Laravel syncing or Attaching / Detaching://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Yes @AdreAstrian the users will be importing the files, so they might make mistakes.
The records don't exist, so unless I'm mistaken it isn't a relation creation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone new enough not to know better :

I ended up keeping the loop + firstOrCreate technique since the loss in time compared to the gain in reliability was minor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$participants = [
    ['participant_id' => 11, 'survey_id' => 1),
    ['participant_id' => 22, 'survey_id' => 2),
];

Participant::insert($participants);
```

But it won't touch timestamps IIRC.

Comment: That is surely faster, but won't test if there already is an item.
Maybe I'll decide this is better with a test on the first item to see if it exists. It's a matter of time gain VS anti-double safety...
Edit : Timestamps aren't necessary for this table.

Comment: I tested several methods but insert doesn't seem to be faster, unless you think my "insert" method can be vastly improved ?